# Javascript for Photoshop, weird error it tells me it expects ;,

Tags: javascript, frameworks, adobe, photoshop

It tells me it expects ; on the line 60. I got this code from a developer who supposably made it all work but now it does not work on my computer.

This is a script made for photoshop js to execute some action based on the condition whether the layer exists ir not.

So what do you guys think what could it be?

I actually have to write stuff more about this since stackoverflow tells me "your post is mostly code but I have no clue what to write. I could maybe add that the name of the layer where action has to be executed is stored in a variable called workingLayer and the value is read out of the file TITLE.txt which is on the desktop.

```
function somename(){
    #target photoshop
    
    var fileRef = "C:/Users/Dharmindar/OneDrive/Desktop/NAME.txt"
    var doc = open(fileRef);
    alert(doc);
}
// this function somename is supposably testing if the name.txt can be opened and it gives an alert 

// this is anther test function I guess to see how to get layers name or document name I am not sure what he did here

function testFunction() {
    var testName = app.activeDocument.name;
    var nameWithoutExt = testName.split(".")[0];
    nameWithoutExt = nameWithoutExt + ", " + app.activeDocument.layers[0].name;
    alert(nameWithoutExt);
}






   //here he lists files from folder desktop and then he loops and searches for a file named TITLE.txt. from there he reads the value that he puts into a layer workingLayer. Later he will execute function based on the fact if the layer exists or not.
function SomeOtherFunction() {
    //Choose the desired folder
    var currentFolder = new Folder('~/desktop/');

    //Get files from the selected folder
    var currentFiles = currentFolder.getFiles(); 
    var selectedFile;

    for (i = 0; i < currentFiles.length; i++) {
        if  (currentFiles[i] == "~/desktop/NAME.txt") {
          selectedFile = currentFiles[i];
        }
    }


 // here he reads the file he opens and equates it to working layer
        selectedFile.open("r");
        var workingLayer = selectedFile.read();
    
        alert(workingLayer);

    var layers = app.activeDocument.layers;
    //alert(layers);

    for (l = 0; l < layers.length; l++) {
        //alert(layers[l].name + " - " + str); 
        var currentLayer = layers[l].name;
         // here he conditions and says if the working layer is equal to the current layer name then execute action exists from custom made 1145Actionset and later he says else, if it does not exist the layer with equal name as working layer then execute action 

        if(currentLayer.name == workingLayer) {
            currentLayer.name = "0";
            ExecuteAction("EXISTS","1145ActionSet");
        } else {
            ExecuteAction("NOTEXISTS","1145ActionSet");
        }

        RenameLayer("0", workingLayer, layers);
    }
}


//here he created function rename layer which is supposed to change layer names after the action has been completed and why was this needed? well it was needed because photoshop actions can not work with variables so what he did he changes the layer name to "0" and then executes action always on layer "0" and then after that he changes the layer 0 back to workingLayer variable value that comes from that TITLE.txt and that is pretty much all there is to it and this weird thing gives me error exactly on the line 60 it says it expects ; 
functon RenameLayer(oldName, newName, layers) {
    for (var j=0;j < layers.length; j++) {
        if (layers[j].name == oldName ){
            layers[j].name = newName;
        }
    }
}


function ExecuteAction(actionName, actionSetName) {
    try {
        //TO DO IF THE LAYER DOESNOT EXISTS
        //Action set must be created first and the action should be in that.
        //The first parameter is the name of th action to be performed and the second parameter is the name of th ActionSet
        app.doAction(actionName,actionSetName);
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}


SomeOtherFunction();
```

Comment: What is line 60 in this code?

Comment: Well, this is a site of enthusiasts who provide help here in their free time and free of charge. The least they can expect is some request and if you post such an amount of code, at least add some annotation where the error occurs and what exactly the error message is ...

Comment: @derpirscher will do so

Comment: The code misspells "function" as "functon".

Comment: Ahaa!! yep I fixed it but now it now for some reason executes action twice.

The action I executed is "NOTEXISTS"